# Can I wrap windows dll to use it in Python under Linux?

Tags: python, linux, dll

Is it possible to wrap Windows DLL (driver for specific hardware) to use it from Python under Linux.

If yes, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Porting (wrapping) drivers (at least kernel mode drivers) should **not** work inside Linux. You'd have to have two parallel systems running in one memory sharing the same global special-meaning registers.

Comment: I'm assuming you do not have access to the source code for this driver?

Comment: The short answer is: most probably not. [NDISWrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper) does this, but for the very specific case of network device drivers. Are you sure the device isn't supported on Linux? Is it a USB device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Depending on the context, the following is certainly NOT the best approach. It is just ONE possible approach that kind of fits the description.*

I wrote a small Python module for calling into Windows DLLs from Python on Linux. It is based on IPC between a regular Linux/Unix Python process and a Wine-based Python process. Because I have needed it in too many different use-cases / scenarios myself, I designed it as a "generic" [`ctypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) drop-in replacement, which does most of the required plumbing automatically in the background.

Example: Assume you're in Python on Linux, you have Wine installed, and you want to call into `msvcrt.dll` (the Microsoft C runtime library). You can do the following:

```py
from zugbruecke import ctypes
dll_pow = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.pow
dll_pow.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double)
dll_pow.restype = ctypes.c_double
print('You should expect "1024.0" to show up here: "%.1f".' % dll_pow(2.0, 10.0))
```

[Source code (LGPL)](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke), [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zugbruecke) & [documentation](https://zugbruecke.readthedocs.io/).

It's still a bit rough around the edges (i.e. alpha and insecure), but it does handle most types of parameters (including pointers).

*I'd be really interested to see how it behaves and performs when used with a hardware driver. Feedback is highly welcomed!*

Comment: After five years I totally forgot about this question and marked is as "undoable" on my list. Thanks for giving it a new life ;) And good luck with your library, looks very promising!